# Failed opening required 'MYSQL'

Tags: php, mysql, require

I keep getting an error 500 when i try to run my php script. I looked in the log and it reads this. 17-Aug-2012 22:35:59] PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'MYSQL' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/aircraft_list.php on line 3
Below are lines one though five of my script

```
<?php
require('http://gatewayaviation.virtual-aviation.org/includes/config.inc.php');
require (MYSQL);
$q = "SELECT CONCAT(aircraft_name, tail_number) AS aircraft, aircraft_type AS at, location AS loc, FROM aircraft GROUP BY location ORDER BY tail_number ASC";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

What is the reasoning behind this. I have been using this same codeing for many of the other pages in the project im working on and there have been no issues. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, I don't think you can require absolute paths.

Comment: `http://gatewayaviation.virtual-aviation.org/includes/config.inc.php` doesn't have any output, so why would `MYSQL` be defined? (For that matter, why would you be including across the internet?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actully figured out the problem with this code. I had put a comma after the loc in the SQL query and that broke the script. It is all fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Giving a distant file to `require` is a security threat since the remote website can change the PHP code in that file in a way that it can harm your server. Besides, including the distant PHP file won't include the PHP code it contains, only the generated HTML. As you can see by visiting the link in your browser, it produces an empty output.

If that file is hosted locally in your server, give require the path to it, not the URL, for example : `require '/var/www/website/includes/config.inc.php'`

As for require(MYSQL), I assume you're trying to include a file called MYSQL ? If that's the case, put it in quotes and make sure you specify the correct path, like this : `require 'MYSQL';` otherwise the interpreter will treat MYSQL as an undefined constant. I don't know what that file might contain but if it's PHP code, it's preferable to give it a .php extension otherwise people might be able to download it and see the code inside it.

Comment: It's also best to be sure the file is actually `MYSQL.php` and not `mysql.php` as not all systems are case insensitive like your development machine might be.

Answer (score -1):

First off, I would recommend the world of OOP. Next, it doesn't appear the MYSQL is defined in your third line and I have never seen it done this way. Here is a reference for you if connecting to your database is the problem. http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/connect-to-mysql-database.aspx

Comment: w3schools is generally a low-quality, massively out of date resource, and the `mysql_*` series of functions are especially awful. Please don't use these in any new applications. `mysqli`, as used in the question, and PDO are significantly better.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I'm not fond of w3 schools either. :( I was just grasping for a path to highlight what I thought my be the problem. Granted, mysqli is a better example. (update link)

Comment: Just as StackOverflow completely squashed Experts Exchange, I hope someone comes along and drives a truck over w3schools. Repeatedly.

Answer (score -1):

this

```
require('http://gatewayaviation.virtual-aviation.org/includes/config.inc.php');
```

is not advised in php and also you can't  just

```
require (MYSQL);
```

rather you have to connect to the database doing something like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

$q = "SELECT CONCAT(aircraft_name, tail_number) AS aircraft, aircraft_type AS at, location AS loc, FROM aircraft GROUP BY location ORDER BY tail_number ASC";
$r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);
```

I think you need to get a tutorial or a php for dummies and read

Comment: -1: the first statement is allowed, and MYSQL presumably is a constant referring to the location of a database configuration file.

Comment: Oh i didn't notice he's using a constant there my bad but you could have pointed that out without down rating me

Comment: The first statement is still allowed in PHP, hence the downvote.

Comment: damn you right!! i don't like it so it always registered in my subconscious as not allowed. Thanks for pointing that out